# Deleting First Node in Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

The following code deletes the first node in a doubly linked list.

```
public Node deleteFirst()
    {
        Node temp = first;

        if(first.next==null)
            last = null;
        else
            first.next.previous = null;
            first = first.next;

        return temp;
    }
```

If the list only contains 1 element we set the reference of last to null. My question is how come we do not set the reference of first to null ? would it even make a difference ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing brackets

this statement will get executed in any case because it is out side of if/else

```
first = first.next;
```

*this is not python*

```
else {
   first.next.previous = null;
   first = first.next;
}
```

Comment: I am using data structres and algorithms for java and they don't have brackets in the book . But i guess that's because they are just demonstrating.

Comment: 2nding Xinzz's comment. I *always* use brackets, including for just one line.

Comment: ok got it, sorry about that error. but can one of you tell my why is last set to null and not first instead?

Comment: last is set to null because if you remove first element from linked list which has only one element there is no last and no first so `null`

Comment: yes but should you not also set first to null? answer posted by ERAN is also suggesting that

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with this method, beside the missing brackets.

```
public Node deleteFirst()
    {
        Node temp = first;

        if (first != null) { // list might be empty
            if(first.next==null) {
                last = null;
                first = null; // you must remove the first element if it's the 
                              // only one, otherwise the next call to deleteFirst
                              // will return the same Node again
            } else {
                first.next.previous = null;
                first = first.next;
            }
        }
        return temp;

    }
```

Comment: So you're suggesting that if there is only one element in a list, you must set both the last and first references to null? My book only sets last to null that's why i am confused because to me it did not make sense.

Comment: What is the full title and author of the book?

Comment: @user2733436 If you don't set `first` to null, you can call `deleteFirst` for a list with a single Node an infinite number of times, and it will always return the same Node.

Comment: @Greycon it is Data Structures & Algorithms in Java Second Edition BY Robert Lafore(see page #227)

Comment: Just heading for a pint now, will take a look at that tomorrow. I agree with @Eran